# Javascript Array filter and extract

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a JSON contains data like this an array and multiples objects in the same level

```
[
   {
      "team":"barcelona",
      "name":"Messi",
      "goals":29,
      "cards":8,
      "played":33
   },
   {
      "team":"barcelona",
      "name":"Grizman",
      "goals":10,
      "cards":8,
      "played":33
   },
   {
      "team":"realmadrid",
      "name":"Hazard",
      "goals":29,
      "cards":8,
      "played":33
   },
   {
      "team":"realmadrid",
      "name":"Benzema",
      "goals":29,
      "cards":8,
      "played":33
   }
]
```

My question is can I convert this into a array like this with javascript function

```
[
   {
      "name":"barcelona",
      "players":[
         {
            "name":"Messi",
            "details":{
               "goals":29,
               "cards":8,
               "played":33
            }
         },
         {
            "name":"Grizman",
            "details":{
               "goals":29,
               "cards":8,
               "played":33
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"realmadrid",
      "players":[
         {
            "name":"Benzima",
            "details":{
               "goals":29,
               "cards":8,
               "played":33
            }
         },
         {
            "name":"Hazard",
            "details":{
               "goals":29,
               "cards":8,
               "played":33
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

so if possible, do that with js function like (filter , push , pop , reduce)
like or i can't and if  other JavaScript implementation will do at this point

Comment: Reduce is a great start, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. easiest way for you now to start with `for` loop iteration of your source array and build your new objects there, and push them to new array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ca use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate all the data you need. For this look for every current object if there exists in the accumulated obbject an property with the team-name as key. If not than create it andd add the property team-name and an empty array for the players.
In both cases add to the player-array the new object for the player. At last take the values from your object to get your desired array.

```js
function transformPlayers(arr) {
    let result = Object.values((arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if (!acc[cur.team])
            acc[cur.team] = {name: cur.team, players: []};
        acc[cur.team].players.push({
            name: cur.name,
            details: {
                goals: cur.goals,
                cards: cur.cards,
                played: cur.played
            }
        });
        return acc;
    }, {})));
    return result;
}

let array = [
   {
      "team":"barcelona",
      "name":"Messi",
      "goals":29,
      "cards":8,
      "played":33
   },
   {
      "team":"barcelona",
      "name":"Grizman",
      "goals":10,
      "cards":8,
      "played":33
   },
   {
      "team":"realmadrid",
      "name":"Hazard",
      "goals":29,
      "cards":8,
      "played":33
   },
   {
      "team":"realmadrid",
      "name":"Benzema",
      "goals":29,
      "cards":8,
      "played":33
   }
];

console.log(transformPlayers(array));
```